# Root of exponential equation

Tags: logarithms

I am trying to find the roots of the equation

$$
e^{x} -\cos x = 0.
$$

Used the Lambert W function to arrive at
$$
x = W(x\cos x),
$$
but I don't know how to proceed from there to get the explicit roots. Any help is much welcome

Comment: I think you will need a numerical method.

Comment: @Sonnhard what numerical method would you suggest?

Comment: The Newton Raphson method

Answer (score 2):

Since $-1\le \cos x\le 1$ and $e^x>0$ with $e^x>1, \; x>0$, by IVT we have infinitely many solutions for $x\le 0$, one is the trivial $x=0$ the others can by found by numerical methods.

Notably we have $2$ not trivial roots for each pair of intervals with $x<0$ such that $0<\cos x<1$ that is for $n=0,1,2,\dots$ that is

$$-\frac{\pi}2 -2\pi n \pi <x<-2\pi n$$

$$-2\pi-2\pi n<x<-\frac32 \pi -2\pi n$$

Note also that for $|x|$ very large, roots are well approximated by the roots for $\cos x=0$ with $x<0$ that is $x\approx -\frac{\pi}2-n\pi$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use numerical methods

You could use maclaurin's expansion

$e^x-\cos x = x+x^2+\frac{x^3}{6}$

Upto 3 degree would be good

Now this becomes a cubic equation
$x=0$

Now this becomes a quadratic equation

$1+x+\frac{x^2}{6}$
 Roots are -4.725,-1.281

For large negative x $e^{-x} \approx 0$ so $\cos x = 0$ which gives $x \approx -(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$ for $n=1,2,3....$$

Answer (score 0):

A supposed hint is that by using the Mclaurin-series for both the $e^x$ and $cos(x)$, we can arrive at this;

$$x^2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{4k}}{(4k+2)!}+\frac{1}{2}\sinh\left(x\right)=0$$

Now take,

$a=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{4k}}{(4k+2)!}$

Now we can get different expressions for the same thing;
$$\ln\left(-2x^{2}a+\sqrt{4x^{4}a^{2}+1}\right)-x=0$$
$$e^{x}4x^{2}a+e^{2x}-1=0$$

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers already told where are more or less located the roots of the equation.

We can obtaing quite good *approximations* of them if, instead of Taylor expansions, we use the simplest $[1,1]$ [Padé approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant). For a function $f(x)$ developed around $x=a$, it would write
$$f(x) \sim \frac{f(a)+ \left(f'(a)-\frac{f(a) f''(a)}{2 f'(a)}\right)(x-a) } {1-\frac{ f''(a)}{2 f'(a)}(x-a) }$$
This is equivalent to a Taylor series up to $O\left((x-a)^3\right)$ and then the approximation
$$x=a+\frac{2 f(a) f'(a)}{f(a) f''(a)-2 f'(a)^2}$$ Using $a=-(2n-1)\frac \pi 2$, in the table below are given the estimates and the solutions for the first roots.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 1 & -1.299002559 &  -1.292695719 \\
 2 & -4.721292643 &  -4.721292759 \\
 3 & -7.853593280 &  -7.853593280 \\
 4 & -10.99559106 &  -10.99559106 \\
 5 & -14.13716622 &  -14.13716622 \\
 6 & -17.27875963 &  -17.27875963 \\
 7 & -20.42035225 &  -20.42035225 \\
 8 & -23.56194490 &  -23.56194490 \\
 9 & -26.70353756 &  -26.70353756 \\
 10 & -29.84513021 &  -29.84513021
\end{array}
\right)$$